# Issues with converting the hourly timestamp from GMT to PDT

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, time, plsql

I'm looking for answers to the below query.

```
   select count(1), to_char(DATE_CREATED,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24') from GDPR where DATE_CREATED>sysdate-1
    group by to_char(DATE_CREATED,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24') order by to_char(DATE_CREATED,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24');

  COUNT(1) TO_CHAR(DATE_
---------- -------------
         4 22-07-2020 02
        32 22-07-2020 03
        33 22-07-2020 09
         7 22-07-2020 14
        26 22-07-2020 15
```

Here the hour field(02,03....) that I'm getting is in GMT. I wanted it in PDT. I tried to cast it in new_time function but it's getting erred out as invalid month. Not sure what's the issue.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `date_created` column?

Comment: Tip of the day: Do not use PDT/PST. Those are abbreviations, instead use the full name, so here use 'US/Pacific'. The difference being the name automatically adjusts for daylight savings the abbreviations (typically) do not.

Comment: DATE_CREATED           DATE    --> datatype

Answer (score 0):

From GMT to PDT you can use new_time. i.e.

```
SELECT date_created, new_time(date_created, 'GMT', 'PDT') FROM gdpr;
```

Make sure, that date_created is of datatype DATE.

To cut minutes/seconds and convert to vc2, use the to_char function with the result of new_time(), i.e. `to_char(new_time(date_created, 'GMT', 'PDT'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24')`